# Connect windows phone 8 with visual studio 2013

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

i have a device which has been registered with a developer account from another pc.
now im trying to connect it to debug in another pc,but its not connecting and showing the phone is developer locked.what could be the solution ,anyone?

if i register device from one pc with a account,the device should be connected in other pc with visual studio right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i register device from one pc with a account,the device should be
>   connected in other pc with visual studio right?

Yes! It should be connected to other PC as well.

Check in you Developer account, whether device is added to your account. If it exists there, means device is no longer developer locked. And you should be able to connect to any pc in visual studio.

Comment: it didnt,i registed the device from usa and later tried to connect it in asia,could there be a problem?

at last i had to remove the device and register it again from my current location to make it work.